# WPF MVVM stop timer when view not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I can start a timer from ViewModel's constructor with no problem. However, I do not understand how to stop it when View is no longer visible. I tried

```
   `Visibility="{Binding ...}"`
```

and

```
  `Unloaded="{Binding }"`
```

but these do not seem to work so the timer goes on forever. The model must stop timer when the View is no longer visible

Comment: Place stop conditions in event that closes your View.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not me who originally designed the app so I can not do that unless I rewrite everything. Please note both Visibility and Unloaded are never received for a reason that is unknown to me

Comment: `Unloaded` is an event, how could you bind to it? And your binding to the `Visibility` property (of your control as I understand) will be overwritten when 'wrapper' of your control (window or other top control) will assign any value to it. You should probably just create public method to be invoked from the same place where something hides your control, as @A191919 has already proposed.

Comment: @hinst, Why you are trying to stop timer when view is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

A very bad posibility would be in the `setter` of the property which is binding to the `Visibility`.

Or the better solution like mentioned above

> Place stop conditions in event that closes your View